# What is the correct way to test classes in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

There is a class named `State` that has several attributes, which I need to write unit tests for. The test will need to have certain actions that change attribute values of the `State` instance. Expected parameters are located inside of the dictionary. The unit test will compare the attributes of the `State` instance with the values of the dictionary for equality.

The question is what is the best place to keep the comparison logic at? I
was thinking about 2 options:

1. Add `__eq__` method to the `State` class that contains comparison logic.
2. Add helper function inside of the test module that contains comparison logic.

Which one of the options is better and why?

Comment: I would say, if you think a by-value implementation of `__eq__` is something you would want in your code anyway, then do that. Otherwise, it's probably best to avoid adding stuff to your production code that is only used in testing. Add a helper function in your test file that does the comparison you want. I am having a little trouble envisioning exactly what you are trying to do, though, so maybe a code example would help clear things up.

Answer (score 3):

Outside. `__eq__` should (in most cases) not be used to compare a specific object to a dict and give equality. The expected behaviour is to enable comparison between objects of the same (or inherited) type. If you're looking for a way to compare to `State` objects, it could be useful - but that doesn't seem to be the case here, according to your description.

I'd also be careful about using `__eq__` for specific tests if these tests *do not explicitly test for equality*, but for certain properties. A future change in `__eq__` - i.e. the comparison requirement between objects of the same class, may not be have the same semantic meaning as what you're *actually testing in your test*. For example; a future change to `__eq__` could introduce more similarity requirements than what your tests require (for example; are they *actually* the same object and not just similar). Since the expected behaviour for `__eq__` is "this represents exactly the same thing", that may not be the same as what you're testing.

Keep the comparison outside of your class - and if it's something you want to re-use in different contexts, either add it as a utility function in your project or add it as a specific function to your object. For now I'd just go with keeping it in your tests, and then moving it inside your project *when it becomes necessary*.

This all assumes that the comparison *is simple*. If there is actual logic and calculations involved - that does not belong in the test. Instead, add logic to your class that exposes the values directly in a properly testable format.

A test should just check that the value returned matches what was expected. However, comparing a returned dict against expected values for that dict is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably take the `__eq__` approach. This way you can also test for equality in the actual code in the future if necessary, while also being able to avoid a potentially messy situation with importing the helper function if you plan or might use type annotations in the future.

Generally you do not want your testing code to contain much logic at all, since test are meant to test code not implement more logic which may need to be tested itself. Beyond the actual test functions you test suites should be really very simple.

The only reason I can think to not take this approach is if the class you are testing has some unique use case where a `__eq__` is not applicable and you want to avoid implementing one and potentially confusing yourself or future developers later on.